# trying to implement Speck32/64 block Cipher

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, block-cipher

I am trying to implement Speck 32/64 block Cipher in c# I'm stuck at encryption decryption algorithm. i know that i should split the plain text in to 2 word according to algorithm

```
x,y = plaintext words
--------------------------- key expansion --------------------------
for i = 0..T-2
[i+m-1] ← (k[i] + S−α
[i]) ⊕ i
k[i+1] ← S
β k[i] ⊕ `[i+m-1]
end for
---------------------------- encryption ----------------------------
for i = 0..T-1
x ← (S−α x + y) ⊕ k[i]
y ← S
βy ⊕ x
end for
```

> ### References
>
> The SIMON and SPECK Families of Lightweight Block Ciphers 
>   https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/404

my question is the plaintext should be string then i convert to binary or what  and use it in the above algo?
the algorithm didnot say the type of plaintext and there is example encryption

```
Key: 1918 1110 0908 0100
Plaintext: 6574 694c
Ciphertext: a868 42f2
```

Answer (score 1):

SPECK 32/64 cipher expects 4 bytes as the input.

> Plaintext: 6574 694c

means

```
byte[] plaintext = new byte[] {0x65, 0x74, 0x69, 0x4C};
```

where each byte is specified as hexadecimal value using the `0x` prefix.

You will divide the plaintext in the first step:

```
byte[] x = new byte[] {plaintext[0], plaintext[1]};
byte[] y = new byte[] {plaintext[2], plaintext[3]};
```

**Note:** use some more clever array manipulation to speed up your cipher, the example above is for educational purposes only.

**Note 2**: handling input as a `uint` might be a good approach, it could be much faster than arrays with a little of bitwise magic:

```
uint plaintext = 0x6574694C;
ushort x = (ushort) (plaintext >> 16);
ushort y = (ushort) plaintext;
```

Comment: Yep, commonly plaintext and ciphertext are displayed as hexadecimals. Ciphers work on binary strings and hexadecimals is the best encoding of binary fit to be read by human beings. That is, when they are byte/octet aligned, but ciphers usually are.